# Data Cloud, CDP, Salesforce CDP, Genie tag alignment

Tags: discussion

There aren't a ton of questions yet, but I'd like to propose a structure to connect and rationalize tags around Salesforce Data Cloud.

There are already three tags competing for which is the best tag: `datacloud`, `cdp`, and `salesforce-cdp`.

CDP evolved into "Genie" in late 2022. But now, most recently, they've killed off the "Genie" product name in favor of Data Cloud. I'd like to propose the following:

- Main Tag: datacloud (already exists)...might add a hyphen to `data-cloud` as the product name does actually have a space in it.

  - Tag Synonyms:

    - cdp (already exists)
    - salesforce-cdp (already exists)
    - genie (doesn't exist)

Since data-cloud is really a next iteration of CDP, but that works across more of the footprint of Salesforce products, to me, it makes sense to not get rid of those tags, rather unite them under the `data-cloud` banner.

Adding the `genie` tag is not necessarily a must-have, but more an effort to head off any mistagging of questions while the branding and product names continue to be fuzzy for a community that always struggles to keep up with Salesforce branding.

My suggested usage guidelines:

> The data-cloud tag is for questions relating to Salesforce Data Cloud administration and implementation. This can include items on the ingestion side of data cloud, such as data streams, data lake objects, harmonization rules. It could also concern output items such as segments, calculated insights, and platform event or web hook activations.
>
> While there can also be ways that data cloud data interacts downstream with Apex or Lightning Web Components, this tag should be used with caution in those instances, unless it really appears as if the data cloud implementation is the actual problem.